# How to add jquery to Wordpress admin pages?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, datetime, datetimepicker

I'd like to add jquery functions to wordpress admin pages via a plugin, but they need to be in the head to work (at least that's the only way I've been able to get them working).

I'm using the `admin_head` hook, but I'm not sure that's the right way to do it. It seems like `admin_enqueue_scripts` is the preferred method, but it doesn't work for me as it loads the script in the footer.

Is there a way to get `admin_enqueue_scripts` to load in the header? Is there a reason not to use `admin_head`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`admin_enqueue_scripts` doesnot load scripts on footer.

You can set the fifth parameter for `wp_register_script()` as false.

Fifth parameter:

> $in_footer (bool) (Optional) Whether to enqueue the script before
>    instead of in the .

```
wp_register_script( $handle, $src, $deps = array(), $ver, $in_footer);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function yournamespace_enqueue_scripts( $hook ) {

    if( !in_array( $hook, array( 'post.php', 'post-new.php' ) ) )
        return;

    wp_enqueue_script( 
        'your_script_handle',                         // Handle
        plugins_url( '/yourfilename.js', __FILE__ ),  // Path to file
        array( 'jquery' )                             // Dependancies
    );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'yournamespace_enqueue_scripts', 2000 );
```